# How to create a simple products programmatically using CSV data in Magento 2 admin?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, csv

I have created a file uploader on my backend admin.
I want to update my products using programmatically by using an csv uploaded.

My controller file is

```
<?php
namespace Tym17\AdminSample\Controller\Adminhtml\SampleTwo;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
 * @var PageFactory
 */
 protected $resultPageFactory;
 protected $csv;
/**
 * @var scopeConfig
 * Needed to retrieve config values
 */

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csv
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->csv = $csv;
}

/**
* Index Action*
* @return void
*/
public function execute()
{
    if (!isset($file['tmp_name'])) 
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Invalid file upload attempt.'));

     $csvData = $this->csv->getData($file['tmp_name']);

     foreach ($csvData as $row => $data) {
         if ($row > 0){
             //Start your work
         }
     }
     die();
}
}
```

I have follow this post https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-read-a-csv-file-convert-it-into-an-array-in-magento-2.html

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small script below and could save a product. This is not recommended to use this script on a production environment as you could be spammed and have thousands of product created if your server allows the access to this route. But at least, it should help you further

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\ProductCreate\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $csv;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    private $productFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csv,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->csv = $csv;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Index Action*
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $csvData = [
            ['header_col0', 'header_col1'],
            ['test', 'dummy']
        ];

        foreach ($csvData as $row => $data) {
            if ($row > 0){

                $data['sku'] = 'sku123';
                $data['price'] = 34;
                $data['name'] = 'Product 123';
                $data['attribute_set'] = 3;
                $data['tax_class'] = 0;

                $product = $this->productFactory->create();
                $product->setSku($data['sku']);
                $product->setName($data['name']);
                $product->setAttributeSetId($data['attribute_set']);
                $product->setStatus(Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
                $product->setVisibility(Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
                $product->setTaxClassId($data['tax_class']);
                $product->setTypeId(Type::DEFAULT_TYPE);
                $product->setPrice($data['price']);
                $product->setStockData(
                    array(
                        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                        'manage_stock' => 1,
                        'is_in_stock' => 1,
                        'qty' => 12
                    )
                );
                $product->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response i have see that please help me with this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320441/saleable-quantity-showing-0-quantity-in-grid-in-magento-ver-2-3-5-p1 @Herve

Comment: @prits this is called moving the goal posts. If the answer I gave you resolved the question you asked, you might think of approving or giving feedback rather than asking another question..